# Unordered array in Foundation?

Tags: objective-c, collections, nsarray, foundation, nsset

We have `NSSet` for a collection of unordered unique elements and `NSOrderedSet` for a collection of ordered unique elements.

Still, we have `NSArray` for a collection of ordered non-unique elements, but no data structure for an unordered list of non-unique elements (as far as I know).

Does this container exist in Foundation? Is there a third-party container that manages such? If not either, is there a *classy* way of getting a randomized sequence of elements from an `NSArray`?

Comment: unordered is not the same as random order.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use arc4random_uniform() which returns random numbers in the range:

example:

```
array[arc4random_uniform(array.count)];
```

Comment: (I didn't mean to get *one* element of the array randomly, rather, to get another array with a randomized sequence of the array's objects.)

Comment: Could you show some code? its can also apply this as well